# Oauth2 by URL from own server to authenticate Google fit [Android]

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-fit

I want to do an Oauth2 service so that my server can request data directly from google fit about users. 
Right now my server makes the connection and returns to me via API a URL in which users put their account and my server automatically saves the token and the refresh token.
The problem is that from Android I send users to a webview where they put their credentials. And I would like to do it with Google's native window to speed up the process and to be able to control when they accept.
I have seen several libraries but none of them do this with a URL, in all of them I have to make the connection with google from the client side.
Is there any way?

That´s the code i used to do the Oauth2.

```
    public void intentToURL(String url){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And i want something like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfhlw.png)

Thanks